# JavaScript converting an array of letters to numbers

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml, onmouseover

I have been working on a function in JavaScript which would permute the letters in a word on mouseenter. I cant get past the first step, which would be converting the letters into numbers to increment their values. First I tried:

```
function permuter1(){
var polygon=document.getElementById("permutable").innerHTML;
polygon = polygon.toLowerCase();
polygon.split("");
var converter = {a:0,b:1, c:2,d:3,e:4,f:5,g:6,h:7,i:8,j:9,k:10,l:11,m:12,n:13,o:14,p:15,q:16,r:17,s:18,t:19,u:20,v:21,w:22,x:23,y:24,z:25};

    for (index=0; index<polygon.length;index++) {
        polygon[index] = converter[polygon[index]];
    }
```

for testing i had been using only:

```
document.getElementById("permutable").innerHTML = polygon[0];
```

and in the html I have:

```
<ul>
<li id = "permutable" onmouseenter="permuter1()" onmouseleave="unpermute1()">Browse</li>
</ul>
```

I would hope that mouseover would give me 1, but instead I got b. so i tried:

```
 for (index=0; index<polygon.length;index++) {

     polygon[index]=polygon[index].charCodeAt();

    }
```

Same result. I even tried:

```
 var str = "";
 for (index=0; index<polygon.length;index++) {
        str=str +polygon[index];
    }

 for (index=0; index<polygon.length;index++) {
        polygon[index] = str.charCodeAt(index);
    }
```

Same result! I tested everything up to the for loop and know that its working. What am I doing wrong in the for loop?

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle to expose the problem ? We need all the functions (unpermute1 too) to be confident on answer

Comment: Looks like there are easier ways to do that -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/684kwLfb/1/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`polygon.split("");` returns an array.  You have to assign it to something in order to use it.  Perhaps you wanted:

```
polygon = polygon.split("");
```

FYI, you can chain some calls together like this:

```
polygon = polygon.toLowerCase().split("");
```

---

In addition, your function `permuter1()` doesn't do anything with the result it calculates to make it visible.  If you want to see it in the web page, you would have to join the array back together into a string with something like `polygon.join("")` and then assign it back to the `.innerHTML` of some DOM element.

Comment: @jonathanbasile - since you may be new here, do you know about the green check mark to the left of an answer to indicate which answer helped you the most?

Answer (score 0):

As @jfriend00 said, split returns an array, and you have to do something with the result. You could do something like this:

```
var polygon=$("#permutable").html();
polygon = polygon.toLowerCase();
var polygonArray=polygon.split("");
var converter = {a:0,b:1, c:2,d:3,e:4,f:5,g:6,h:7,i:8,j:9,k:10,l:11,m:12,n:13,o:14,p:15,q:16,r:17,s:18,t:19,u:20,v:21,w:22,x:23,y:24,z:25};
var result="";
    for (index=0; index<polygon.length;index++) {
        if(converter[polygonArray[index]]){
        result=result+converter[polygonArray[index]];
        console.log(result);
        }

    }
    if(result)$("#permutable").html(result);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hhalse/u24us682/)